# document.getelementbyid().style.width has no value

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I wrote afew code to call a function in javascript for alerting value of top of a div. But it doesn't work. It seems I have forgotten a simple point but I can't find it.

Script is:

```
var tempimg = "";
var tempdiv = "";


function changebg(x) {
    current = document.getElementById(x);
    alert(document.getElementById('div1').style.width);

}
```

and CSS is:

```
.div11 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms;
    -moz-transition: 1000ms;
}
.div22 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 120px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms;
    -moz-transition: 1000ms;
}
.div33 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 230px;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms;
    -moz-transition: 1000ms;
}
```

I put my code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Salman_Sharifi/42NVE/2/)

Answer (score 3):

Use `getComputedStyle` instead:

```
alert(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('div1')).height);
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style):

> it is not useful for learning about the element's style in general,
>   since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the element's
>   inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules
>   elsewhere, such as style rules in the  section, or external
>   style sheets

i.e. It returns the values represented by `<div style="<!-- these values -->"></div>` and not the styles applied by external CSS.